# Do I have to put parent::__construct($config) in my CakePHP data source?

Tags: cakephp, datasource

Is there a good reason to put

```
parent::__construct($config)
```

in the construct of a CakePHP data source I am developing? I see it being used in some of the data sources found in https://github.com/cakephp/datasources/blob/master/models/datasources/amazon_associates_source.php but not sure why. I could just do

```
private $_config = array();
function construct($config){
    $this->_config = $config;
}
```

and access my $config the same way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at DataSource class in CakePHP, it's constructor call setConfig method. Here is setConfig method source:

```
function setConfig($config = array()) {
    $this->config = array_merge($this->_baseConfig, $this->config, $config);
}
```

You can see that it will merge several configuration. So you can define $config attributes in your class and it will merge with whatever user give to constructor. Of course you can do this in constructor:

```
function __construct($config){
    $this->setConfig($config);
}
```

But calling parent constructor will ensure your class to follow whatever change CakePHP made in DataSource class.

Comment: thanks dude! did you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719500/when-does-cakephp-call-the-is-connect-method-in-a-data-source